# Is there an analytic function that takes on every value apart from 3 numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis

After reading about little Picard's theorem , the great Picard theorem and the great Picard theorem for meromorphic functions and the alike I started thinking.

These theorems talk about taking every value apart from 1 or 2 for entire functions or functions with essential singularities.

But what happens when we have analytic functions without essential singularities ?

For instance $\ln(z)$ does not take on many values.
But $\sqrt z$ takes on all complex values.

Most analytic functions have an essential singularity at infinity so I assume they take on all values apart from at most 2 values ? ( using the Great Picard theorem and mapping the infinity to the finite ).

Can the range of an analytic function be " complicated " , I mean can it have a complicated topology with many holes and bifurcations ?

I anticipated that the way we choose the branches influences the range , but I think the cardinality of the values we do not take on is not changed by that ??

To start simple and not to general I ask :

Is there an analytic function that takes on every value apart from 3 numbers ?

And please give an example.

I looked in the books but could not find any theorem claiming that an analytic function can not take on every value apart from 3 numbers. So I guess the matter is either very trivial or very complicated ?

Does Riemann mapping help here ?

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{z}$ does not take on all complex values.  Which values it does take depends on which branch you choose.

For an analytic function that takes on all but $3$ complex values, take 
$f(z) = z$ on the complex plane with those $3$ points removed.

If you're asking for an entire function that takes on all but $3$ complex values, that is forbidden by Picard's "little" theorem.

Comment: The range of the analytic function $f(z)=z$ is the entire complex plane. There are no points removed.
Picard's little theorem is known to me see the OP.
But not all analytic functions are entire !
Is the range of $\sqrt z$ not equal to the entire complex plane ? Care to explain ?

Comment: There are points removed if you define the domain of the function to have those points removed.
As for $\sqrt{z}$, if you use the "principal branch" its values are in the right half-plane plus the positive imaginary axis.

Comment: I want the full complex plane as domain. But exactly 3 points not in the range of $f(z)$.